# How to appeal a question's status as exact duplicate?

Tags: support

My question was closed as an exact duplicate; however, I don't think it is, since my question addresses a more specific capability of the iOS keyboard in terms of Unicode (not just symbols).

So I'd like to know how, if possible, I might appeal a moderator's decision to mark it as exact duplicate? Is there a way I can contact the moderator?

[How can I type or input Unicode characters using a code point on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/how-can-i-type-or-input-unicode-characters-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to edit your post so that it's clear that it's not a duplicate, then flag it for moderator attention asking for us to take another look.

In any case, based on what you've said, I've edited your title and reopened your question.